# Haskell defined types

Tags: haskell, types

Studying Haskell first principles. Absolute beginner in Haskell. 
If:

```
data A
data B
func :: A -> B
func = undefined
```

What would the actual function be? Worked though load of exercises with great result (also thanks to you) but again I am stuck. Does A -> B indicate two different types like 'String' -> 'Char'? Just trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: No uppercase types are real types. Whereas lowercase types are type variables.

Comment: If that's the actual code, then `undefined` is, in some sense, the only valid definition for `func`. `B` isn't inhabited, so there is no way to return a value of `B` from `func`. (For that matter, there is no way to call `func` either, since there aren't any values of `A` to provide as an argument.)

Answer (score 6):

No, (concrete) **types start with an Uppercase**. So `A -> B` means the types `A` and `B` you have defined (well not defined here) with your `data A = ...` expressions, like for instance:

```
data A = Foo | Bar Int | Qux String A
```

In case the signature contains an identifier with a **lowercase**, it is a **type variable**. For instance `foo :: a -> b`, means `a` and `b` can be substuted by any type. So `foo` is a function that can be `A -> B`, but also `A -> Int`, `Char -> B`, and `Char -> Int`.

You can also add **type constraints** to the signature to restrict the types for which for instance `a` and `b` can be used. Like `foo :: (Show a, Num b) => a -> b` restricts `a` and `b`, such that there should exist an `instance Show a` and `instance Num b` for the types `a` and `b` such that `foo` is defined over these types.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks Willem, Chepner. Your answers helped me out to conjure up:

```
data A
data B
funcAJ :: A -> B
funcAJ a = a
       where a = b
             b = undefined
```

This typechecks as funcAJ :: A -> B, which I understand. Thanks so much!

Comment: That doesn't do what you probably think it does. The `a` in the `where` is shadowing the function parameter `a`. They are different variables with the same name. The `a` that is the function parameter is of type `A`, whereas the one defined in the `where` and returned from the function is of type `B`. This is because it is defined to evaluate to `b` which is in turn defined as `undefined`. And undefined can take on (pretty much) any type. So this is just a fancy way of writing `funcAJ a = undefined`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, but had high hopes I figured it out. I am lost now. Can you pose a function that type-checks and is correct?

Comment: Unless you give your types `A` and `B` some data constructors `undefined` (or other constructs that return bottom) is the only possible implementation for a function of type `A -> B`.